# Unable to instantiate default tuplizer Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, annotations, mapping

Recently I updated my hibernate from 3.1 to 4.3 and I am trying to use annotations instead of xml.With Xml everything is working fine and annotation throw up a bunch of exceptions. And the final one I am stuck with is the below stack trace please shed some light on it. I terribly need a help because the stack trace is not giving me any specific area to work on.

I am using:
Hibernate 4.3
javaassist 3.18

I tried to use javaassist jar which everyone suggested but that didn't help me. However I have my doubts, buildSessionFactory is deprecated for hibernate 4.5 and is this a culprit by any chance?
Just including my HibernateUtils if it of any help

```
Properties connProperties = new Properties();
                connProperties.setProperty( "hibernate.connection.datasource", "java:comp/env/" + MASTER_JDBC_RESOURCE_NAME );
                configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.addProperties(connProperties);
                sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
                Properties hibernateProperties = configuration.getProperties();
                for (Object k : hibernateProperties.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println("Hibernate Key "+k.toString());
                }
                String testCon = hibernateProperties.getProperty("hibernate.test_connections");
                testConnections = StringUtils.stringToBool(testCon);
```

My Stacktrace

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:101)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.(ComponentMetamodel.java:81)
> at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:180)
> at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
> at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:271)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
> at wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.(HibernateUtils.java:111)
> at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.(BaseDAO.java:43)
> at wadetech.DB.DAOS.__MaintenanceDAO.(__MaintenanceDAO.java:10)
> at com.at.project.utils.runtime.RuntimeModifier.HasExecuted(RuntimeModifier.java:127)
> at wadetech.listeners.ModificationScriptStartupListener.contextInitialized(ModificationScriptStartupListener.java:47)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
> ... 22 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property bytes in class java.lang.String
> at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:246)
> at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:240)
> at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:328)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildSetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:159)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:65)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:59)
> ... 27 more

Thanks for any help

Comment: I tried to use buildSessionFactory with ServiceRegistry, and still its not working.

Comment: This exception doesn't have anything to deal with buildsessionfactory However the culprit was a table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for a solution and unfortunately most of the answers that solved for others dint help me.A couple of the most voted answers is mentioning below:

1. Use of javaassist.jar and make sure when you use its compatible with your hibernate version. For hibernate 4.3.11 javaassist 3.18 is okay.
2. Make sure you define matching getters/setters for all your properties.

My case was similar to case 2 so if anyone stuck with these errors and if case 1 dint help you, only thing you can do is a full check-up and comparison of your entity class with the table and column name. For me my task was to move the mapping from XML to annotation, and anyone facing issue due to this migration needs to cross-check their entity class with corresponding .hbm.xml files.